# Dark brown leisons on the underside of the hot pepper leaves

Tags: peppers

There are dark brown leisons on the underside of the leaves and the leaves eventually turn yellow and fall off. Leisons are not visible on the upper side, also not water soaked or with a yellow halo surrounding it so I am thinking of ruling out bacterial leaf spot, so what would be causing it and the solution?[image]